# Complex analysis find the set of points?

Tags: complex-analysis

Describe the set of the points in the plane which satisfies the following :

a) $$ z=t^2 + (i/t^2) $$

and the second exercise is

b)$$ z= α*e^{i*t} + β*e ^{- i*t} $$

Now,I have solved exercises with the same question but the exercise was like |z+2|= |3+i|...not like this! Do you have any clue how to solve this?

Comment: try using LaTeX to write mathematics in this site, otherwise it's hard to understand what's going on  there... are $\,\alpha,\beta,b,t\in\Bbb R\,$ or what?

Comment: Fixed it :) thank you

Comment: No, not yet fixed: you haven't told us where are those values taken from.

Comment: Lo siento ,mi hijo.We take them from R.

Comment: Take a peek and be sure the following is what you meant: $$z=t^2+\left(\frac i{t^2}b\right)z=\alpha e^{it}+\beta e^{-it}$$

Comment: Nooo they are two different exercises

Comment: Well, your expression **still** is incorrect since you have two right parentheses there (left side) but only one left parentheses...

Comment: I corrected them again

Comment: Don Antonio donde estas? Te necesito :/

Comment: Dooooooon Antonioooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: Please keep it quiet = manténte tranquilo y sin escenas: a veces la gente no sabe la respuesta, otras veces toma un poco de tiempo escribirla y/o explicarla. Hay que ser paciente.

Comment: You will get the most out of this site by treating it and its users with respect.  Define your question properly (which you *still* haven't done), and show a little patience.

Comment: Don Antonio,yo te amo,y yo estoy muy loca cuando m'enamoro :/ :/ Lo siento....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one you want all the points of the form

$$\left(x^2\,,\,\frac1{x^2}\right)\in\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb C$$

and this is a hyperbola-like set of points in the plane: in fact, you could try to draw it just like with the "normal" hyperbola $\;y=\frac1x\;$ but always squaring both sides (and thus the graph is always on the upper half plane), with $\,x=0\;$ as vertical asymptote.

As for the second one:

$$z=\alpha e^{it}+\beta e^{-it}=(\alpha+\beta)\cos t+i(\alpha-\beta)\sin t$$

and this is a a canonical ellipse with $\;x-$radius equal to $\,\alpha+\beta\;$ and $\,y-$radius equal to $\,\alpha-\beta$

Comment: Eres l'amor de mi vida.Gracias.This is the exact answer in my book.